# Unit Testing of async methods .NET 4.0 style

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have library functions in the library that I developed that execute asynchronously.
Description by example:

```
private void Init()
{
     // subscribe to method completion event
     myLib.CompletionEvent += myLib_CompletionEvent; 
}

private void MyButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // start execution of Func1 
    myLib.Func1(param1, param2);
}
```

the Func1 initiates some processing in the library and immediately returns.

The result is of the processing arrives to the client as an event through a delegate

```
void myLib_CompletionEvent(ActionResult ar)
{
    // ar object contains all the results: success/failure flag 
    // and error message in the case of failure.
    Debug.Write(String.Format("Success: {0}", ar.success);
}
```

So here is the question:
How do I write Unit test for this?

Comment: I recommend you to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207631/how-to-write-unit-test-cases-for-async-methods

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend creating a task based asynchronous method using a [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then using the support for `async\await` by testing frameworks such as MsTest and Nunit to write an asynchronous unit test. The test must be marked as `async` and is usually required to return a `Task`

You can write the asynchronous method like this(untested):

```
public Task Func1Async(object param1, object param2)
{
   var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    myLib.CompletionEvent += (r => 
    {
        Debug.Write(String.Format("Success: {0}", ar.success));

        // if failure, get exception from r, which is of type ActionResult and 
        // set the exception on the TaskCompletionSource via tcs.SetException(e)

        // if success set the result
        tcs.SetResult(null);
    });

    // call the asynchronous function, which returns immediately
    myLib.Func1(param1, param2);

    //return the task associated with the TaskCompletionSource
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Then you can write your test like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test()
    {
         var param1 = //..
         var param2 = //..

         await Func1Async(param1, param2);

         //The rest of the method gets executed once Func1Async completes

         //Assert on something...
    }
```

Comment: Although fine approach, I have a few problems with it: 1. It is not what I asked. 2. I doubt if it works: in Test Method aka Test() the "rest of the method gets executed once Func1Async completes" - but the process in the library did not complete yet...(Func1Async returns immediately and so does myLib.Func1)

Comment: `Func1Async` returns immediately but it returns a `Task`, once the task is complete the rest of the method gets executed. Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736736/how-does-await-async-work